# Javascript null array and populate with image BLOB

Tags: javascript, php, arrays, null, blob

I have a javascript append function populating cards on my site.  I am pulling images from a database and then setting that php array to a javascript array.  However, sometimes there may be no image in database so I want to populate with a default image saved in my site directory.  I do not want to store a default image for every database entry that doesn't have an image.  Figured pulling from site the default image would save space in database.  So how can I set my javascript array below to my default image if no image is found in it?

```
var jImages = []; 
<?php
for ($i = 0; $i < count($Image); $i += 1) {
  echo 'jImages['.$i.'] = "'.base64_encode($Image[$i]).'";';
}
?>
```

this is the beginning portion of my append function where I am actually setting my jImages.

```
        $(document)
        .ready(function() {

            $.each(tagNumbers, 
                function(i, value) {
                    $('.main_card_shell').append(
                    "<div class='card_content card_style' id='card0'>" +

                           "<div class='subcard_style box_title'>" + 
                               '<img class="card_image" src="data:image/png;base64,' + jImages[i] + '" alt="Item #1" />' +
```

Not sure if it is as easy as setting jImages to the default image path since I am using "data:image/png:base64".

Answer (score 0):

The default image should be base64 encoded. You can get the base64 string of your default image for example [here](https://www.base64-image.de/).

Then check the value of $Image[$i] in your for-loop. If it is the value that stands for no image in DB, set jImages['.$i.'] to the base64 string of you default image.

```
<?php
for ($i = 0; $i < count($Image); $i += 1) {
  $b64Str = /* base64_encoded default image */;
  if ($Images[$i] != /* whatever the value is if no image in DB */) {
    $b64Str = base64_encode($Image[$i]);
  }
  echo 'jImages['.$i.'] = "'.$b64Str.'";';
}
?>
```

Comment: thanks for the comment, so do I just go $b64Str = base64_encode("path of image")??

Comment: No. You need to convert the image into a base64 string. Please try the link that I posted in my answer.

Comment: ahhh so my string will be very long right? I just tried the link you gave.

Comment: Yes, the string can be very long. Depends on the size of your image. 4*[n/3] characters for an image the size of n byte.